# how to build Qt 6.2.2 from source with MSVC on windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, qt, cmake, build-tools

I want compile Qt 6.2.2 from source with VC Build Tools 2019 16.11 and CMake 3.22. but I encountered 1 problem during implement

```
cmd input : ...\"my_qt_source_dir"/QtBase> configure -debug-and-release -static -prefix "E:\qt-build" -opengl desktop -nomake tests -nomake examples
```

[cmd output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d59Ju.png)

Is there any workaround here? Help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect the error message to be in the **question post** as **text**, not linked as *image*. Please, (re-)read [ask] and [edit] the question post accordingly.

Comment: The error in your link suggests a stale CMakeCache.txt file. Try deleting it and rebuilding. Also, I notice that you included the -static option in your configure command. If your end-goal is to produce fully static images, you'll also need the -static-runtime option. Finally, note that building a static version of Qt requires the non-static version of Qt to exist on your system.